# Rounding for estimates on averages

Tags: arithmetic, estimation, rounding-error

I am reading the following simple problem on rounding.

> Traveling at an average rate of between $60$ and $70$ miles/hour for $3$ to
> $4$ hours select the best estimate for the distance traveled
> a) $90$ miles
> b) $190$ miles
> c) $225$ miles
> d) $275$ miles

I thought the following:
Since it is between $60$ and $70$ and $3$ to $4$ then if we round up/down we have:
$$60 \cdot{3} = 180$$ or
$$70 \cdot{3} = 210$$ or
$$60 \cdot{4} = 240$$ or
$$70 \cdot{4} = 280$$

So it seems to me that the answer should be **d** since $280 - 275 = 5$ is the smallest difference among with all the other options. But the solution says **c**.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just grasping:  average between $60$ and $70$ is $65$, and average between $3$ and $4$ is $3.5$.  Then, $65\times3.5=227.5$, which is closest to **c**.

Comment: @AndrewChin: The context where I read this is about rounding numbers to do calculations not round after doing them. Perhaps I misunderstood the idea then

Comment: You should add them and divide by $4$. That gives you $227.5, $ and $228$ if you round it. $225$ is the closest. There is no reason why you should pick $280$ because that is the maximum possible distance traveled based on the given data and not average.